# canary --disable-web-security doesn't work any more for ajax requests in AngularJS project

Tags: ajax, angularjs, security, google-chrome, cross-domain

Starting canary with argument --disable-web-security does not help any more to send cross domain AJAX requests while developing on localhost

I see a message in console

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://[some-domain-name].com. 
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. 
Origin 'http://localhost:3100' is therefore not allowed access.
```

How can I set header for ajax request in AngularJS project?

P. S. I use an alias to start canary with required args

```
alias canary="open -a \"Google Chrome Canary\" --args --disable-web-security"
```

Comment: If it's in dev mode, can you not allow 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' on the server side?

Comment: @SergeSeletskyy, hi, is there way to make same things for Safari? I can't find it.

Comment: Hi @baxxabit. That is a good question. Unfortunately I don't have an answer and have to stick with Chrome development only.

Comment: @SergeSeletskyy, there is no option. We use proxy server to disable cors

Comment: This seems to be a bug only in Canary (works as expected in latest stable Chrome). Chrome sees the flag and displays the warning http://i.imgur.com/g32rm1o.png but fails to allow cross domain requests. It did work a couple of days ago.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**EDIT**

Working solution: use the command `open -a Google\ Chrome\ Canary --args --disable-web-security --user-data-dir=$HOME/profile-folder-name`.

Explanation: `--disable-web-security` now requires the use of the `--user-data-dir` flag.

Windows command: `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --disable-web-security --user-data-dir=%USERPROFILE%\profile-folder-name`

---

This seems to be a bug only in Canary (works as expected in latest stable Chrome). Chrome sees the flag and displays the warning but fails to allow cross domain requests. It did work a couple of days ago.

I reported the issue: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=575690

Comment: The value for `--user-data-dir` should be `-user-data-dir=$HOME/Library/Application\ Support/Google/Chrome\ Canary/`

Comment: @davidcondrey I think you may use any directory you want to. I personally prefer to create a specific folder for this, instead of using the path to the app itself (which might lead to problems in the future).

Comment: I just noticed that when I ran the command it created the same directory structure that already existed in the Application Support directory.

Comment: can you please help how to use the command 'open ....', I am using Chrome in Windows 7

Comment: @khoailang I edited my answer with a command that works on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Try to close the browser and open it with special argument again.

Canary is being updated often and when you accept to update it it restarts without special arguments.